# how to delete data in laravel 5.4 through third model relation

Tags: laravel, model, relationship

I am new in laravel and using laravel version 5.4.
I have three model named Projects, Tasks, and TaskStatus.

```
`class Project extends Model {
    public function tasks() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Task', 'project_id', 'id');
    }
}`
```

and second model as

```
`class Task extends Model {
    public function taskStatus() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\TaskStatus', 'task', 'id');
    }
 }`
```

I am trying to delete all status like this:

```
$this->project->find($project_id)->tasks()->taskStatus()->delete();
```

it shows me error like this:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::taskAssign()

How can I solve this error?

Comment: The error shows `taskAssign()`, i don't see it being used anywhere in your code.

Comment: can you show the whole function where you try to delete the status

Comment: Please edit your question to include your controller method for deletion here.